How to Configure proxy.config.json file with ssr server.ts file in angular version 17.3
I am using proxy.config.json to handle CORS errors in my app. However, the ssr server.ts file can't deal with this proxy config in development and as a result for all HTTP request its response is HTML code instead of a JSON response.o, my question is how to make SSR deal with my proxy config?
Note: I upgraded my angular from version 16 to 17 and convert it from Module to standalone app.
I added this part of code to server.ts file:
if (!environment.production) {
  const proxyOptions: any = {
    target:
      'https://tmg-ksa-admin-dev.cloud/',
    secure: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    timeout: 600000,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/local': '',
    },
    onProxyReq: (
      proxyReq: ClientRequest,
      req: IncomingMessage,
      res: ServerResponse
    ) => {
      console.log('Proxying request:', req.method, req.url);
    },
    onProxyRes: (
      proxyRes: IncomingMessage,
      req: IncomingMessage,
      res: ServerResponse
    ) => {
      let body: Buffer[] = [];
      proxyRes.on('data', (chunk: Buffer) => {
        body.push(chunk);
      });
      proxyRes.on('end', () => {
        const responseBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log('Received response:', proxyRes.statusCode, responseBody);
      });
    },
  };

  server.use('/local', createProxyMiddleware(proxyOptions));
}

It work when I run these commands:
npm run watch
npm run serve:ssr:project-name

However, when I run normal server using ng s -o, it doesn't work.

I found answer in this question : proxy config with angular 17

From the angular docs:

If you get an ECONNREFUSED error using a proxy targeting a localhost URL, you can fix this issue by updating the target from http://localhost:<port> to http://127.0.0.1:<port>.
See the http-proxy-middleware documentation for more information.

